# ASP.NET MVC saving list to cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can i save `List<T>` to cookie in a controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of data you can store into a cookie is limited and depends on browsers. Generally it's about 4K. So the first thing you need is to serialize this list. There are different possibilities here depending on the data you are serializing: you could use [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), [JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), [binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) with [base 64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) encoding, ...

Once the list is serialized you you could use the [AppendCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerresponse.appendcookie.aspx) method to emit the cookie:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string value = SerializeList(someList);
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("SomeCookieName", value);
    Response.AppendCookie(MyCookie);
}
```